# Set a default value in a combobox from enum

Tags: c#

I have a combobox that I have some values in from an enum.

I want a default value to show on the combobox when the program start.. but I cant get it to work..
This is what I have tried so far in my MainForm:

```
cmbPrio.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(PriorityType.Prioritytypes)));
cmbPrio.SelectedValue = PriorityType.Prioritytypes.Normal;
```

this is the class with the enum:

```
class PriorityType
{
    public enum Prioritytypes
    {
        Very_Important, 
        Important, 
        Normal, 
        Less_Importan
    }
}
```

Comment: set **SelectedIndex**

Answer (score 3):

You are populating the names into the combo, which is just a collection of string, which means that values you use to set must also be strings.

```
cmbPrio.SelectedValue = Enum.GetName(typeof(PriorityType.Prioritytypes), PriorityType.Prioritytypes.Normal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply set the `Index`? :

```
cmbPrio.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: I used this and now it works:
cmbPrio.SelectedIndex = (int) PriorityType.Prioritytypes.Normal;

Comment: Thats not correct actually. Suppose if you have a value `5` and total no. of items in the list are just 3. Your code will do `cmbPrio.SelectedIndex = 5;`. More than the range of the item list. It'll through an exception. You should set a `Index` or a `Value`. Do not combine them

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to set the ComboBox items to:

```
cmbPrio.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(PriorityType.PriorityTypes))
                           .Cast<PriorityType.PriorityTypes>());
cmbPrio.SelectedValue = PriorityType.PriorityTypes.Normal;
```

This allows you to treat the selected values as actual `PriorityType.PriorityTypes` as opposed to strings.